# Uncaught Error: Module name "@cloudant/cloudant" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([]) in javascript

Tags: javascript, requirejs, cloudant

I am using cloudant database but it is giving problem in require. I have used webpack to add the library of Require but none of it is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked the clouding library and it is not an AMD module. It is a CommonJS module, so please read the docs: https://requirejs.org/docs/commonjs.html this will probably help you